# Tengo un problema con mi aplicacion de recordatorios, no salta notificacion alarma

Tags: java, android, android-studio, sqlite

Mi aplicacion consiste en una agenda con recordatorios, comienza con un main menu donde se puede elegir entre dos opciones, crear una actividad o ver el calendario. Si nosotros seleccionamos el boton de crear una actividad nos lleva a otra vista donde nosostros rellenaremos los campos con los datos de la actividad(nombre de la actividad, fecha, hora y num de avisos) y luego cuando le damos al boton de crear se crea un registro en un base de datos SQLite donde nos guarda toda la informacion y luego se usa en otra vista llamada VerCalendario donde hay un calendario y un list view el cual si nosotros seleccionamos una fecha en el calendario nos muestra en el listview las actividades asignadas a esa fecha, a parte debe de saltar una alarma media hora antes de la hora asignada a ese registro, que se muestre una notificación para la alaram con un boton de detener.

Tengo estos codigos, me imagino que solo se necesitaran el codigo de crear la actividad, la base de datos donde se almacena y la vista de calendario:

**CrearActividad**

```
public class CrearActividad extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {
    Button btnHora, btnFecha, btnPantallaPrincipal, btnCrear;
    EditText txtHora, txtFecha, txtNombreTarea;
    Spinner spn;
    private static final int REQUEST_CODE_VER_CALENDARIO = 2;
    private int dia, mes, anyo, hora, minutos;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_crear_actividad);

        btnFecha =(Button) findViewById(R.id.btnFecha);
        btnHora =(Button) findViewById(R.id.btnHora);
        txtNombreTarea = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtNombreTarea);
        txtHora =(EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtHora);
        txtFecha =(EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtFecha);
        spn = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spnAvisos);
        btnPantallaPrincipal = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnVolver);
        btnCrear = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnCrear);

        btnHora.setOnClickListener(this);
        btnFecha.setOnClickListener(this);

        String[] opciones = {"1", "2", "3"};
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, opciones);
        adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);

        spn.setAdapter(adapter);


        btnPantallaPrincipal.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                // Crea un Intent para poder volver a la pantalla principal
                Intent intent = new Intent(CrearActividad.this, MainActivity.class);

                // Inicia la nueva actividad
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });

        btnCrear.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String infoNombreTarea = txtNombreTarea.getText().toString();
                String infoHora = txtHora.getText().toString();
                String infoFecha = txtFecha.getText().toString();
                String selectedValue = spn.getSelectedItem().toString();

                if (TextUtils.isEmpty(infoNombreTarea) || TextUtils.isEmpty(infoHora) || TextUtils.isEmpty(infoFecha) || TextUtils.isEmpty(selectedValue)) {
                    // Muestra un Toast si falta información
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Por favor, rellena todos los campos", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                } else {
                    // Guarda la información en la base de datos SQLite
                    DatabaseHelper dbHelper = new DatabaseHelper(CrearActividad.this);
                    SQLiteDatabase db = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();

                    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
                    values.put(DatabaseHelper.COLUMN_NOMBRE_TAREA, infoNombreTarea);
                    values.put(DatabaseHelper.COLUMN_HORA, infoHora);
                    values.put(DatabaseHelper.COLUMN_FECHA, infoFecha);
                    values.put(DatabaseHelper.COLUMN_SELECTED_VALUE, selectedValue);

                    long newRowId = db.insert(DatabaseHelper.TABLE_TAREAS, null, values);
                    db.close();

                    // Verificar si la fecha del nuevo registro es igual a la fecha actual
                    Calendar fechaActualCal = Calendar.getInstance();
                    String fechaActual = dbHelper.obtenerFechaFormateada(
                            fechaActualCal.get(Calendar.YEAR),
                            fechaActualCal.get(Calendar.MONTH) + 1,
                            fechaActualCal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)
                    );

                    if (!infoFecha.equals(fechaActual)) {
                        // Crea un Intent para pasar a VerCalendario solo si la fecha no es la fecha actual
                        Intent intent = new Intent(CrearActividad.this, VerCalendario.class);
                        // Pasa la fecha como extra para que VerCalendario pueda mostrar la información correcta
                        intent.putExtra("fecha", infoFecha);
                        // Inicia la nueva actividad y espera un resultado
                        startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CODE_VER_CALENDARIO);
                    }
                    // Programar la alarma
                    NotificationService.programarAlarma(getApplicationContext(), newRowId, infoNombreTarea, infoHora, infoFecha);

                }

            }
        });

    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        if (view == btnFecha) {
            final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
            dia = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
            mes = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
            anyo = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);

            DatePickerDialog datePickerDialog = new DatePickerDialog(this, new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {
                    // Crea un nuevo Calendar con la fecha seleccionada
                    Calendar selectedDate = Calendar.getInstance();
                    selectedDate.set(year, monthOfYear, dayOfMonth);

                    // Compara la fecha seleccionada con la fecha actual
                    if (selectedDate.getTimeInMillis() >= System.currentTimeMillis()) {
                        // La fecha seleccionada es válida, actualiza el texto en txtFecha
                        txtFecha.setText(dayOfMonth + "/" + (monthOfYear + 1) + "/" + year);
                    } else {
                        // La fecha seleccionada es anterior a la fecha actual, muestra un Toast
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Selecciona una fecha válida", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        txtFecha.setText(""); // Limpia el campo de fecha si no es válida
                    }
                }
            }, dia, mes, anyo);
            datePickerDialog.getDatePicker().updateDate(anyo, mes, dia);
            datePickerDialog.show();
        }

        if (view == btnHora) {
            final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
            hora = c.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
            minutos = c.get(Calendar.MINUTE);

            TimePickerDialog timePickerDialog = new TimePickerDialog(this, new TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener() {
                @Override
                public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int minute) {
                    // Crea un nuevo Calendar con la hora y fecha seleccionadas
                    Calendar selectedDateTime = Calendar.getInstance();
                    selectedDateTime.set(Calendar.YEAR, anyo);
                    selectedDateTime.set(Calendar.MONTH, mes);
                    selectedDateTime.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, dia);
                    selectedDateTime.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, hourOfDay);
                    selectedDateTime.set(Calendar.MINUTE, minute);

                    // Compara la fecha seleccionada con la fecha actual
                    if (selectedDateTime.get(Calendar.YEAR) == c.get(Calendar.YEAR)
                            && selectedDateTime.get(Calendar.MONTH) == c.get(Calendar.MONTH)
                            && selectedDateTime.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH) == c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)
                            && selectedDateTime.getTimeInMillis() >= System.currentTimeMillis()
                            &&

                            selectedDateTime.getTimeInMillis() <= System.currentTimeMillis()) {
                        // La fecha es la fecha actual y la hora seleccionada es anterior a la hora actual, muestra un Toast
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Selecciona una hora válida", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        txtHora.setText(""); // Limpia el campo de hora si no es válida
                    } else {
                        // La fecha seleccionada es válida, actualiza el texto en txtHora
                        // Formatea el minuto con un cero delante si está entre 0 y 9
                        String formattedMinute = (minute >= 0 && minute <= 9) ? "0" + minute : String.valueOf(minute);
                        txtHora.setText(hourOfDay + ":" + formattedMinute);
                    }
                }
            }, hora, minutos, true);
            timePickerDialog.show();
        }
    }

}
```

**La Base de datos**

public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

```
    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "miaplicacion.db";
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

    public static final String TABLE_TAREAS = "tareas";
    public static final String COLUMN_ID = "_id";
    public static final String COLUMN_NOMBRE_TAREA = "nombre_tarea";
    public static final String COLUMN_HORA = "hora";
    public static final String COLUMN_FECHA = "fecha";
    public static final String COLUMN_SELECTED_VALUE = "selected_value";

    public DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        String CREATE_TABLE_TAREAS = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_TAREAS + "("
                + COLUMN_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,"
                + COLUMN_NOMBRE_TAREA + " TEXT,"
                + COLUMN_HORA + " TEXT,"
                + COLUMN_FECHA + " TEXT,"
                + COLUMN_SELECTED_VALUE + " TEXT"
                + ")";
        db.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE_TAREAS);
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_TAREAS);
        onCreate(db);
    }

    public List<String> obtenerInformacionPorFecha(String fecha) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
        List<String> informacion = new ArrayList<>();
        String[] projection = {
                COLUMN_ID,
                COLUMN_NOMBRE_TAREA,
                COLUMN_HORA,
                COLUMN_FECHA,
                COLUMN_SELECTED_VALUE
        };

        // Obtener todos los registros para la fecha especificada
        String selection = COLUMN_FECHA + "=?";
        String[] selectionArgs = {fecha};
        Cursor cursor = db.query(TABLE_TAREAS, projection, selection, selectionArgs, null, null, null);

        while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
            long idRegistro = cursor.getLong(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(COLUMN_ID));
            int nombreTareaIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(COLUMN_NOMBRE_TAREA);
            int horaIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(COLUMN_HORA);
            int fechaIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(COLUMN_FECHA);
            int selectedValueIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(COLUMN_SELECTED_VALUE);

            String nombreTarea = cursor.getString(nombreTareaIndex);
            String hora = cursor.getString(horaIndex);
            String fechaBD = cursor.getString(fechaIndex);
            String selectedValue = cursor.getString(selectedValueIndex);

            // Combina los datos en una sola cadena
            String combinedData = idRegistro + " | " + nombreTarea + " | " + hora + " | " + fechaBD + "  |  " + selectedValue;

            // Agrega la cadena combinada a la lista
            informacion.add(combinedData);
        }
        cursor.close();
        db.close();
        return informacion;
    }
    public String obtenerFechaActual() {
        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        int year = calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR);
        int month = calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH) + 1; // Los meses comienzan desde 0
        int dayOfMonth = calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

        return obtenerFechaFormateada(year, month, dayOfMonth);
    }
    // Método para editar un registro existente
    public void editarRegistro(long id, String nuevoNombreTarea, String nuevaHora, String nuevaFecha, String nuevoValorSeleccionado) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(COLUMN_NOMBRE_TAREA, nuevoNombreTarea);
        values.put(COLUMN_HORA, nuevaHora);
        values.put(COLUMN_FECHA, nuevaFecha);
        values.put(COLUMN_SELECTED_VALUE, nuevoValorSeleccionado);

        // Actualiza el registro en la base de datos
        String selection = COLUMN_ID + "=?";
        String[] selectionArgs = {String.valueOf(id)};
        db.update(TABLE_TAREAS, values, selection, selectionArgs);
        db.close();
    }


    // Método para obtener una cadena de fecha formateada (por ejemplo, "30/11/2023")
    public String obtenerFechaFormateada(int year, int month, int dayOfMonth) {
        return String.format(Locale.getDefault(), "%02d/%02d/%04d", dayOfMonth, month, year);
    }

    public void eliminarRegistro(long id) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        String selection = COLUMN_ID + "=?";
        String[] selectionArgs = {String.valueOf(id)};
        db.delete(TABLE_TAREAS, selection, selectionArgs);
        db.close();
    }
    public List<String> obtenerInformacionPorId(long id) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
        List<String> informacion = new ArrayList<>();
        String[] projection = {
                COLUMN_ID,
                COLUMN_NOMBRE_TAREA,
                COLUMN_HORA,
                COLUMN_FECHA,
                COLUMN_SELECTED_VALUE
        };

        // Obtener el registro para el ID especificado
        String selection = COLUMN_ID + "=?";
        String[] selectionArgs = {String.valueOf(id)};
        Cursor cursor = db.query(TABLE_TAREAS, projection, selection, selectionArgs, null, null, null);

        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            int nombreTareaIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(COLUMN_NOMBRE_TAREA);
            int horaIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(COLUMN_HORA);
            int fechaIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(COLUMN_FECHA);
            int selectedValueIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(COLUMN_SELECTED_VALUE);

            String nombreTarea = cursor.getString(nombreTareaIndex);
            String hora = cursor.getString(horaIndex);
            String fechaBD = cursor.getString(fechaIndex);
            String selectedValue = cursor.getString(selectedValueIndex);

            // Combina los datos en una sola cadena
            String combinedData = id + " | " + nombreTarea + " | " + hora + " | " + fechaBD + "  |  " + selectedValue;

            // Agrega la cadena combinada a la lista
            informacion.add(combinedData);
        }

        cursor.close();
        db.close();
        return informacion;
    }
    public void eliminarTodosLosRegistros() {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

        // Elimina todos los registros de la tabla
        db.delete(TABLE_TAREAS, null, null);

        // Cierra la conexión a la base de datos
        db.close();
    }
}
```

Por favor necesito que cuando se cree un registro en CrearActividad tambien se asigne una alarma junto a el que se active media hora antes de la hora asignada al registro y que genere una notificacion alarma junto a el que se pueda detener.(con vibracion y sonido) Gracias